# Why is a second then returned before the first?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I'm trying to understand ES6 promises, and for a second there, I thought I had it, but I guess not.

So I want to create / read a bunch of files and only after this operation has completed, move on to do the next operation. To me, this lends itself nicely to Promises, but I'm getting confused as to why my second operation is returning before my first operation has completed.

I've created a function `ensureFileExists` which returns a promise, and I pass this as a callback into `fileNames.map`. This logs an  array of `true` to the console, which is what I'd expect. But my confusion is, I thought that my seconded `then` would only get called after my first `then` has completed.

If anyone could elaborate on why my second `then` is returning before my first `then`, I'd be grateful.

```
getFileNames(ensureFileExists) {
  for(let i = 0; i < this.fileCount; i++) {
    this.fileNames.push(this.generateRandomfileNames());
  };
  Promise.all(this.fileNames.map((file) => ensureFileExists(file)))
         .then(values => console.log(values))
         .then(console.log(1)) // Why is this logged before values???
         .catch(err => console.log(err))
};

ensureFileExists(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let filePath = path.join(this.src, file);

    fsExtra.ensureFile(filePath, (err) => {
      if (err === 'undefined') {
        reject(new Error('Error creating file'));
      } else {
        resolve(true);
      }
    });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
.then(console.log(1))
```

Calls `console.log` immediately, and passes the return value into the `then` method.

You probably want something more like the callback function in your prior line, like this:

```
.then(() => console.log(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you're not passing `console.log` as a callback function, but you're executing it immediately and passing the returned value (`undefined`) to the `then` argument.

In the second `then`, you pass an anonymous function, but you're not executing it.

Like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log("inside myFunction()");
}

function then(fnCallback) {
    console.log("inside then()");
    fnCallback();
}


then(myFunction);
    /*  Log:
        inside then()
        inside myFunction()
    */



then(() => myFunction() );
    /*  Log:
        inside then()
        inside myFunction()
    */        



then(function() { myFunction() });
    /*  Log:
        inside then()
        inside myFunction()
    */        



/* what happens here:
    1) executes myFunction(), that returns undefined
    2) executes then() with undefined as argument
    3) try to call fnCallback (which is undefined), and trows an error
*/
then(myFunction());
    /*  Log:
        inside myFunction()
        inside then()
        Uncaught TypeError: fnCallback is not a function
    */
```